# AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<500> while testing getMapping with RequestParam

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5, spring-test

I am using junit5 and getting a 500 error instead of 200 while testing  a getmapping. Even going through the full stacktrace i am not able to understand where i am doing wrong. I do not see any issue with the get mapping the way i am calling it in unit test method and the service layer is mocked. I am not able to understand why it is throwing 500 and no debug point is working. Need help

**Actual method:**

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/sample/findData/rest",
              produces = {
                  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE
          })
          public ResponseEntity<ResponseObj> findData(
              @RequestParam(name = "Param1") String param1,
              @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String token) {
        
            JSONObject jwtToken = Util.getTokenAsJson(token);
        
            String convertedStirngToFind =
                Util.convertToString(
                    param1,jwtToken); // doing some action for message preparation
        
            ServiceResponse processResponse =
                findService.findService(
                    convertedStirngToFind); //calling service layer to dao layer
        
            return new ResponseEntity<>(processResponse.getDataResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
          }
```

**Unit Test method:**

```java
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @WebMvcTest(controllers = FindController.class)
    public class FindControllerTest {
        
        @MockBean FindService findService;
        
        @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;
        
        @Test
          void testFindData() throws Exception {
    
            
            String param1 = "test_Data";
            String token = "<<token>>"; //passing actual token here
    
    
            JSONObject jwtToken = Util.getTokenAsJson(token);
            
            String convertedStirngToFind =
                    Util.convertToString(
                        param1,jwtToken);
            
            
            ServiceResponse mockServiceResponse = mock(ServiceResponse.class);
            
            
            
            Mockito.when(findService.findService(convertedStirngToFind)))
            .thenReturn(mockServiceResponse);
    
            RequestBuilder requestBuilder =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/sample/findData/rest")
                    .header("Authorization", token)
                    .param("param1", param1);
    
            mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
            
          }
      
          
         }
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
        at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
        at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
        at com.sample.rest.controller.FindControllerTest.testFindData(FindControllerTest.java:111)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: Is that the only stacktrace you have? I would have expected a stacktrace of the spring boot app (not just the assertion junit exception)

Comment: that's the only trace i am getting.. running jacocotest, or junit on the java class.. same error is only getting logged

Comment: Is it ok, that you have `Param1` in controller and `param1` in test?

Comment: sorry it is just a typo... i can't change it now... prarameter name is Param1 in both the files

Comment: can you please guide in some way?